# Generating random divs with sizes that fit

Tags: php, jquery, html, image

I'm wanting to make a uniform grid of divs that are fulfilled, as in the picture. However I do not like to follow a pattern for this, they would be finished in a random way without entering the space of the other. How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this accomplished nicely by using Masonry, a cascading grid layout library, have a look 
http://masonry.desandro.com/